# Filling in gaps on 2m raster, with 30m raster

Tags: qgis, raster, contour

I have a raster file in QGIS which contains some gaps that I would like to fill with the global 30m data. I have been successful doing this with 1m and 2m data, using the 'Align Raster' tool, and it retains the accuracy of the 1m file but fills the gaps with the 2m data. I am struggling to achieve the same thing here.

I have reprojected the 30m layer so they are both on same CRS, 27700. I am able to merge them, but then it defaults to 30m accuracy. I am getting an error when trying to use the Align tool.

The aim is to have them on a single layer, so I can create contours.

[image]

Comment: bump bump bump bump